# Unique constraint on a column

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I've created a Table t1 in Sql Server 2008:

```
create t1  
    (id int primary key,  
    name varchar(50) null,  
    city varchar(50) unique  
    )
```

Now i want to get property of each column in a C# program. I can write:

```
foreach(Column cl in t1)  
   if(cl.nullable)  
        ......
```

But I'm unable to check a given column for a `Unique` constraint

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Good formatting is your friend..

Comment: Because "uniqueness" is **not** a property on a column - but either a column constraint, or an index, perhaps!?!??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then read the property [`DataColumn.Unique`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.unique%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? It seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: tnx for guidance. but i sholud analysis ke database shcema directly and i need konw is a columns in unique or no? how can do it????? plz help me!